# jQuery UI tabs not working on touch devices (with touchPunch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I'm trying to implement jQuery-UI tabs alongside touchPunch in order to allow clicks to be mapped to touch events. However touch devices still don't recognize touches and the tabs therefore don't switch.

This is the script I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="html/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="html/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({event:'click' ,hide:'fadeOut', show: 'fadeIn'}).addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
        $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );

    });
</script>
```

I also tried changing the event to 'touchstart' and 'click touchstart', neither of them working (and the first one disabling click too).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT - this is the html code used

```
<div id="tabs" class="navtext" style="position: fixed; top: 73vh; left: 0.5vw; height: 25vh;">
    <ul style="list-style: none; font-size: 1.5vw">
        <li><a href="#Presets">Presets</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="#Channels">Channels</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Presets">
        <div class="navtext" id="LayoutList"
             style="left: 9vw; height: 20vh;top: 1vh; width: 0; POSITION: absolute; background-color: transparent; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Channels">
        <div class="navtext" id="ChannelList"
             style=" width: 0; top: 1vh; POSITION: absolute; background-color: transparent; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use tabs, too, and it works on Ipads although my jquery version is a little higher. Have you tried the init without any parms (not sure whether the click interferes):  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active:0 });

Comment: @Jobst I just tried it and I still don't register any touch events, either on my Nexus 6 or on my iPad

Comment: my version of jquery is 1.11 (runs within WP theme) a) what is the html for the tabs and b) do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @Jobst So I updated to the latest version (1.11.4), to no avail, and the console shows no errors... EDIT - it now works on my iPad, but my nexus 6 still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I am at a loss - my tabs working on all my touch devices without touch-punch. Put the tabs inside a division with some padding and margin so you are sure there is no other "things" preventing your finger be seen by the touch device.

Comment: Anyways thanks for your help @Jobst i'll update if I find a solution!